# Gow to limit viewport-based layout by static px value?

Tags: css, flexbox, resolution

There is a set of already written HTML documents with similar CSS layout.

Designer have applied CSS viewport stuff extensively using viewport properties. So, on 1920px it looks great, on higher resolution - bad.

Please, place here suggestions - how to wrap current design by some width? For example, if we have 21x9 monitor, can we place content with proper ratio on the middle, remaining left and right fields empty?

[image]

Any resolution starting with 1920 should be supported.

Comment: You can use media queries for that.

Comment: Would an iframe suffice?

Comment: I will check both options. Thank you for reply!

Media query - huge overwrite, iframe - security issues? Or I am wrong?

Comment: There is no simple "wrapper" solution?

Comment: It depends on the content whether you've got iframe issues, e.g. if the site tries to link to another site that doesn't allow itself to be run in an iframe. I don't see how there can be an overall wrapper given you apparently have lots of media queries which are looking at the viewport dimensions rather than at a parent element's dimensions.